# how to get an array of each uploaded file

Tags: arrays

I have some problem with my array, how to get an array of each file_name for insert as a record databases, Thanks

and this is the Array

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => Chrysanthemum14.jpg
    [file_type] => image/jpeg
    [file_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/
    [full_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/Chrysanthemum14.jpg
    [raw_name] => Chrysanthemum14
    [orig_name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
    [client_name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 858.78
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 1024
    [image_height] => 768
    [image_type] => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
)
```

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => Desert10.jpg
    [file_type] => image/jpeg
    [file_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/
    [full_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/Desert10.jpg
    [raw_name] => Desert10
    [orig_name] => Desert.jpg
    [client_name] => Desert.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 826.11
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 1024
    [image_height] => 768
    [image_type] => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
)
```

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => Hydrangeas10.jpg
    [file_type] => image/jpeg
    [file_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/
    [full_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/Hydrangeas10.jpg
    [raw_name] => Hydrangeas10
    [orig_name] => Hydrangeas.jpg
    [client_name] => Hydrangeas.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 581.33
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 1024
    [image_height] => 768
    [image_type] => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
)
```

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => Jellyfish10.jpg
    [file_type] => image/jpeg
    [file_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/
    [full_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/Jellyfish10.jpg
    [raw_name] => Jellyfish10
    [orig_name] => Jellyfish.jpg
    [client_name] => Jellyfish.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 757.52
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 1024
    [image_height] => 768
    [image_type] => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
)
```

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => Koala10.jpg
    [file_type] => image/jpeg
    [file_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/
    [full_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/Koala10.jpg
    [raw_name] => Koala10
    [orig_name] => Koala.jpg
    [client_name] => Koala.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 762.53
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 1024
    [image_height] => 768
    [image_type] => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
)
```

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => Lighthouse10.jpg
    [file_type] => image/jpeg
    [file_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/
    [full_path] => F:/xampp/htdocs/pariwisata/panorama/image/Lighthouse10.jpg
    [raw_name] => Lighthouse10
    [orig_name] => Lighthouse.jpg
    [client_name] => Lighthouse.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 548.12
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 1024
    [image_height] => 768
    [image_type] => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
)
```

Comment: First: What language is this? Second: What have you tried doing and how did it not work? You should not expect people to do your work for you

Comment: what u trying to say and what data that u have shown? i agree with Unholysheep u must try first before ask and are this files uploaded in any folder?